# Dictionary, array or list for quick searching of indexes and values

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, dictionary, listbox

I have 100,000 strings each with a fixed ordered index value like this:

```
Index   String Value
  0     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  1     XXXXXXXXXX
  2     (empty string)
  3     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  4     XXXXX
  5     XXXXXXXXX
  6     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  7     (empty string)
  8     XX
  9     XXXXXXXXXX
 10     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 ...    ...
99999   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

My data structure must hold exactly 100,000 ordered entries and some (or many) of the string values may be empty, at least initially.  Each index value will be unique (sequential integers) and, with the exception of empty strings, each string value will also be unique.  For display purposes in my UI, I'd normally just populate my data structure, bind the listbox to it (with a DisplayMember and ValueMember specified).  But in this case, I only want to display the strings that are *not* empty.  So presumably, I'll need to iterate through my data structure and add the applicable items to a listbox in a manner similar to this:

```
foreach (item in MyDataStructure)
{
    if (item.StringValue != string.Empty)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

It's very important for me to be able to maintain the relationship between each string and its index value at all times.  As you might expect, my users will need to add/edit/delete strings.  In theory, all three operations boil down to the same thing: updating a string value at a particular index.  To add a new string, I'll need to first iterate through my data structure and make sure that there's an empty string somewhere so I can replace it with the new string.  If no empty strings exist, my user will need to "edit" an existing string or "delete" another string first because we're dealing with a fixed number of total strings (100k).  From a programmatic perspective, "deleting" a string is also just a matter of replacing it at the appropriate index in my data structure with an empty/null string.

As best as I can foresee, I'll need a data structure that makes it easy to do the following:

1. Add the index and string values for every non-empty string to a listbox and use the index as a ValueMember and the string as the DisplayMember.
2. Quickly search the data structure for a particular index and retrieve its string value
3. Quickly search the data structure for a string to see if it already exists

With those things in mind, can anyone recommend a particular data structure that lends itself to the task?  I was initially thinking a dictionary with key/value pairs to hold each index/string.  Then someone suggested just using an array since the total size is fixed and the array index itself could also serve as the index value for each string value.

Comment: What is the relationship between the index and the string value? Also, why does there have to be a fixed number of 100,000 total strings?

Comment: call me insane but why don't you use a database?(hash table is your only viable option here)

Comment: Just as a side note to my answer - why do you always need to have 100'000? Can't you start at 0 and then add, just set a maximum of 100'000 then add/remove/edit the list.

Comment: The 100,000 limit is due to the hardware device that will ultimately consume the data.  Basically, it has 5,000,000 bytes of storage to hold 100,000 ASCII-encoded strings at 50 bytes/string.  That device accesses the strings by calculating the offset to start at (index * 50) and then reading/writing for the next 50 bytes.

Comment: @user685869 - That doesn't invalidate LukeHennerley's question, though.  The limit makes sense, but unless you need to specifically have exactly 100,000 strings, you could just set an arbitrary list and limit it in the UI code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you have a fixed amount of items in your `List` and you require an index for each item, you need look no further than an array.

```
string[] arr = new string[100000];
```

You get access to `LINQ` for the array too so you can meet your criteria.

```
//1
arr.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(str => new { value = Array.IndexOf(arr, str), display = str });
//2
string str = arr[index];
//3
arr.Any(x => x == "SomeString");
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is a [dual-dictionary](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/273361/Csharp-Most-efficient-way-to-implement-dual-Dictio).  Essentially keep *two* dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<int, string> // index-->value
Dictionary<string, int> // value-->index
```

It will be a little more work to keep the dictionaries in-sync but if you do a lot of searching by the value it may be worth it.

Using an array will require linear searches every time you search for a value so I don't think it will be the most performant.

Also, if you just don't store blank/null values in either dictionary then you can bind directly to them without having to do any filtering.

Answer (score 0):

There are of course lots of ways to do this, but you could create a collection class than encapsulates a `SortedDictionary<int, string>` with your non-empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way... You have memory limit of 5mb and you're going to use the entire thing holding blank strings? Is this data structure going to be held in the 5mb too? That limits the number of strings you can hold. How are the strings being persisted in this memory? Some sort of database? I don't know what this is being used for, but do you really think your users will use all 100,000 strings? I highly doubt that.

I also still don't understand how the keys relate to the string values, but it really does not make sense to me to have a list of 100,000 items, most likely a lot of those being empty strings. It's a waste of memory, not to mention the search/insert/delete overhead it will create. Keeping the list of only what is currently used makes much, much more sense when thinking of speed.

I would suggest using a [`NoSQL`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database if at all possible. You can insert the strings that users create, which gives you your index values, and can update the strings at will. If a user deletes/sets a string to an empty string, you can remove it from the database (or, since you're really keen on this idea, set it to an empty string within the database). Keep inserting until you hit your 100,000 string limit.